# Reload Parse data without PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

Is there a way you can reload parse data without using PFQueryTableViewController. I have used the `[self loadObjects]` command and it works for tables created using PFQueryTableViewController but not for tables that retrieve parse data without using PFQueryTableViewController. Sorry if this is confusing. Id be happy to clarify it. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to run your query again. This is exactly what `PFQTVC` does, it calls the `queryForTable` method which returns your query and then reloads the table with the new data. If you don't want to use a `PFQTVC`, then all you have to do is run your query again by calling the method your query is in, or just putting it in your current method, then call `[self.tableView reloadData];`